# Conditional e-mails based on radio buttons Drupal Webform

Tags: webforms

I've built a form at http://dev.vies.dk/tilmelding. In the backend, it is easy to send e-mails to people filling out the form.

However, I need to send additional e-mails to other people based on some of the answers in the webform, namely the subjects they choose and the sex they have.

```
Subject         Female       Male
Soccer          mail@mail.dk mail@mail.dk
Handball        my@mail.dk   your@mail.dk
Kayak           mail@mail.dk mail@mail.dk
Dance           be@mail.dk   eb@mail.dk
Biking          sv@mail.dk   ls@mail.dk
```

Is there a hook, where this can be programmed, so I can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want to use [hook_mail_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) in a custom module. This will intercept the outgoing email from Drupal and allow you to add programming logic to the process. For example you could:

- Load the webform in question and view its results.
- alter the `to` value of the `$message` to meet your needs.

> 'to': The address or addresses the message will be sent to. The
>   formatting of this string will be validated with the [PHP e-mail
>   validation filter](http://php.net/manual/filter.filters.validate.php).

Comment: How would you load the webform, because when I grasp that, I think I might be good to go?

Comment: You probably dont want the webform itself, you want the submission by a given user. You want to look at the webform API, and at least the function [webform_get_submissions](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21webform%21includes%21webform.submissions.inc/function/webform_get_submissions/7). Also if you simply do a `node_load()` on a `NID` with a webform -- you get the webform itself back as apart of the Node.